# How to remove file from the server after uploaded by uploadify/uploadifive

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify, uploadifive

I am using [uploadifive](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) to upload files on the server. While the file is being uploaded on the server and a user clicks on the (x) icon the upload will stop.

However, after the file is uploaded. If a user click on the (x) I want to remove that file from the server completely.

I tried to use `onCancel` event but that gives me the file information on my local machine. I will need the final file name that was saved on the server (I rename file before copying them on the server.)

How can I remove he file when the use clicks the (x) icon.

Thank you

Comment: just ignore the file completely. php already automatically removes the temporary file it creates to store the upload, UNLESS you take steps to preserve it (e.g. `move_uploaded_file()`).

Comment: After the temp file is uploaded and moved via `move_uploaded_file()`  so I want to get the final file name after  `move_uploaded_file()` then issue a `unset` to remove it from the server

Comment: m_u_f() requires YOU to provide the path/filename of where the file's being moved to. you should already have that information somewhere.